# Why doesn't comparison work in CONVERT?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Is it possible to use a comparison operator in a CONVERT or CAST function?

I've got a statement that looks like this:

```
SELECT
    ...
    CASE field
        WHEN 'Y' THEN 1  # If Y then True
        ELSE 0           # Anything else is False
    END
    ...
FROM ...
```

A similar thing happens for a few fields, so I would like to change it to a shorter version:

```
SELECT
    ...
    CONVERT(BIT, field = 'Y')
    ...
FROM ...
```

But MSSQL is giving an error `Incorrect syntax near '='.`

My interpretation of the help is that it should work:

- `CONVERT ( data_type [ ( length ) ] , expression [ , style ] )`
- `expression: expression { binary_operator } expression`
- `binary_operator`: Is an operator that defines the way two expressions are combined to yield a single result. binary_operator can be an arithmetic operator, the assignment operator (=), a bitwise operator, a comparison operator, a logical operator, the string concatenation operator (+), or a unary operator.
- `comparison operator: ( = | > | < | >= | <= | <> | != | !< | !> )`

I ran a few tests and got these results:

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIT, 0)       // 0
SELECT CONVERT(BIT, 1)       // 1
SELECT CONVERT(BIT, 1+2)     // 1
SELECT CONVERT(BIT, 1=2)     // Error
SELECT CONVERT(BIT, (1=2))   // Error
SELECT CONVERT(BIT, (1)=(2)) // Error
```

Comment: field='Y' is an assignment, not an expression. In any case, a bit data type can only contain a 0 or 1. The CASE statement is correct since it assigns 1 when field='Y'.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you are misinterpreting the documentation for `CONVERT`. There is nothing in the documentation for `CONVERT` that states it will handle an expression that makes use of the comparison operators, only that it accepts an expression. It turns out that `CONVERT` does not handle every valid SQL expression. At the very least it cannot handle the results of an expression that uses a comparison operator.

If you check the documentation for [Operators](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa276846%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), you'll see that the comparison operators (which is what you want `=` to be, in this case) return a `Boolean` data type, and are used in WHERE clauses and control-of-flow statements. From the documentation for Operators:

> The result of a comparison operator has the Boolean data type, which has three values: 
>   TRUE, FALSE, and UNKNOWN. Expressions that return a Boolean data type are known as 
>   Boolean expressions.
>
> Unlike other SQL Server data types, a Boolean data type cannot be
>   specified as the data type of a table column or variable, and cannot
>   be returned in a result set.
>
> ...
>
> Expressions with Boolean data types are used in the WHERE clause to
>   filter the rows that qualify for the search conditions and in
>   control-of-flow language statements such as IF and WHILE...

That helps to explain why SQL like `SELECT 1=2` is invalid SQL, because it would create a result set with a `Boolean` data type, which the documentation says is not allowed. That also explains why the CASE WHEN construct is necessary, because it can evaluate the comparison operators and return a single value of a data type that SQL Server can return in a result set.

Furthermore, if you look at the documentation for [CONVERT](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa226054%28v=sql.80%29.aspx), you'll see that `Boolean` is not supported in either `CAST` or `CONVERT` (see the table towards the middle of the page, there is no `Boolean` data type in there).

For your purposes, I think you're stuck using `CASE WHEN`. If it helps you can write it all on one line:

```
CASE WHEN field = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END
```

Alternatively, you could create a UDF to handle the CASE expression (something like `dbo.func_DoCase(field, 'Y', 1, 0)`), but personally I would just stick with `CASE WHEN`.

Comment: +1 I suspect you're right. I was going to say exactly this but you beat me to it.

Comment: @Wiseguy: Thanks. I know that the SQL `SELECT CONVERT(BIT, 1=2)` is invalid, but trying to figure out exactly why using the documentation is a bit difficult.

Comment: Yeah, you would think the documentation would clearly point this out and/or the error thrown would be more helpful. "Incorrect syntax" sounds more like a simple typo rather than "well, you're assembling the pieces correctly but for non-obvious reasons that I don't feel the need to explain they don't belong in this particular location."

Comment: @rsarro, Thanks for the explanation and reference to the documentation. My sanity is now restored :)